# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las variables aparezcan aleatorias?

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, me generó una duda al momento de realizar mi código, tengo el siguiente código, pero al momento que me aparecen en pantalla quisiera que me salieran las opciones de manera aleatoria, o sea, que no me salga 1,2,3,4 sino que me salga 2,3,1,4 o de cualquier otra manera pero sin orden

```html
        <?php
        include '../conn.php'; 
          $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
          mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

          $sn=@$_GET['n'];
          $quiz=@$_GET['quiz'];

          if ($sn === '1') {
             $id_Resultado = uniqid();
          }else{
            $id_Resultado = @$_GET['idRes'];
          }

          $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas_comp_teo WHERE COMP_ID='$quiz' AND NO_PREGUNTA=$sn";
          //$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM preguntas_comp_teo WHERE COMP_ID='$quiz' AND NO_PREGUNTA=$sn";
          echo '<div class="panel" style="margin:5%">';
          //echo $sql;
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          $c=1;
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $pregunta = $row['PREGUNTA'];
                $id_pregunta = $row['PREG_ID'];
                $op1 = $row['OP1'];
                $op2 = $row['OP2'];
                $op3 = $row['OP3'];
                $respuesta = $row['OP4'];

                  echo '<form action="Cactualiza.php?q=1&quiz='.$quiz.'&n='.$sn.'&idRes='.$id_Resultado.'&preg='.$pregunta.'&skip=no" method="POST" class="form-horizontal"><br />';
                  echo '<b>Pregunta &nbsp;'.$sn.'&nbsp;:<br />'.$pregunta.'</b><br /><br />';

                  if ($op1 !== "") {                  
                    if ($op1 === "PREGUNTA") {                      
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op1.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($op2 !== "") {
                    if ($op2 === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op2.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($op3 !== "") {
                    if ($op3 === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op3.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($respuesta !== "") {
                    if ($respuesta === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="1" required>'.$respuesta.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }
                  echo'<br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Guardar</button></form></div>';
                }
```

AL momento de que me imprime los resultados me los muestra de manera en cómo se guardaron en el sistema. No sé si lo más sencillo sería meterlo en un ciclo o no si hubiera alguna variable para que me muestre las opciones de manera aleatoria.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! agregale un valor aleatorio a cada fila y luego ordena por el mismo

Comment: Por favor explica qué quieres decir con lo de aleatoria. Nos dejas aquí todo el código para que analicemos, adivinemos la lógica y encontremos el problema. Si nos dices directamente el asunto sería más fácil para todos ¿no?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo yo se refiere a que si tienes un indice de preguntas. Te aparezcan de forma desordenada cada vez que entres en la página. Esto evitaría que la gente diga "la 1, la 2" y evitar intentar comparar respuestas después

Comment: @matahombres si a eso me refiero lo que quiero es saber como le puedo hacer para que las opciones no me aparezcan en orden, sino que cada vez que un usuario se meta salgan en diferente orden

Comment: Solamente tienes que agregar esto a la consulta que trae los datos: **`ORDER BY RAND()`** de eso modo los datos vendrán ordenados de forma aleatoria. Si esta es la consulta, quedaría así: **`SELECT * FROM preguntas_comp_teo WHERE COMP_ID='$quiz' AND NO_PREGUNTA=$sn ORDER BY RAND()`**

Comment: La consulta es de preguntas y no de respuestas (creo). Y dentro de la línea de cada pregunta tiene las posibles respuestas. Lo que quiere hacer es hacer un random de las posibles respuestas y para ello deberás utilizar PHP haciendo un  `rand(0,count($array_respuestas))` a un array de respuestas creado previamente

Comment: pero para crear el array se tendría que meter en un ciclo?

Comment: ya hice la prueba @matahombres como tu dices pero me quita algunas veces la opcion que es correcta

Comment: Escribo un ejemplo en respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nueva respuesta**
Viendo tardaba mucho en ejecutar he investigado un poco y he encontrado una función que hace un desorden de un array. `shuffle($array);`

**Ejemplo**

```
$array_respuestas=array($resp1,$resp2,$resp3);
shuffle($array_respuestas);
```

Documentación: [PHP.net > shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php)

**Antigua respuesta:**

**Explicación:**
Al tener en la BD las posibles respuestas dentro de la misma tabla (y no en otra tabla linkeadas) no se puede utilizar `ORDER BY RAND()` y por ello se tiene que hacer la selección en **PHP**
Las solución que veo yo sería crear un array de las respuestas y luego hacer un `rand(0,count($array_respuestas))` al array de respuestas.
**Como el `rand()` no detecta que respuesta está ya puesta** deberemos de hacer otro array con el indice de las respuestas ya puestas para detectar si está puesta o no.

**Ejemplo**

```php
.
.
.
$array_respuestas=array($resp1,$resp2,$resp3);
$respuestas_puestas=array();
$array_desordenado=array();
//Utilizamos el bucle for para recoger el indice
for($i=0;$i<count($array_respuestas)-1;$i++){
    $ya_puesto=false;
    do{
        $ran=rand(0,count($array_respuestas));
        if(in_array($ran,$respuestas_puestas)){
            $ya_puesto=true;
        }else{
            //Añadimos al array el elemento actual
            $respuestas_puestas[]=$ran;
            $array_desordenado[]=$array_respuestas[$ran];
        }
    }while($ya_puesto);
}
.
.
.
```

De esta manera tienes 3 arrays.

1. Array original `array_respuestas`
2. Array de elementos ya puestos `respuestas_puestas`(Comprobación interna)
3. Array original desordenado `array_desordenado`

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\evalua.php on line 415 me genera este error y este otro cuando entra por primera vez Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\evalua.php on line 409

Comment: He encontrado una mejor solución te la pongo

Answer (score 0):

```
**ahorita estoy haciendo la prueba para ver como saldria el rand pero en los que he hecho se me va la op4 la cual es la respuesta correcta**   
     <?php
        include '../conn.php'; 
          $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
          mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

          $sn=@$_GET['n'];
          $quiz=@$_GET['quiz'];

          if ($sn === '1') {
             $id_Resultado = uniqid();
          }else{
            $id_Resultado = @$_GET['idRes'];
          }

          $sql="SELECT * FROM preguntas_comp_teo WHERE COMP_ID='$quiz' AND NO_PREGUNTA=$sn";
          //$sql="SELECT count(*) FROM preguntas_comp_teo WHERE COMP_ID='$quiz' AND NO_PREGUNTA=$sn";
          echo '<div class="panel" style="margin:5%">';
          //echo $sql;
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          $c=1;
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $pregunta = $row['PREGUNTA'];
                $id_pregunta = $row['PREG_ID'];
                $op1 = $row['OP1'];
                $op2 = $row['OP2'];
                $op3 = $row['OP3'];
                $respuesta = $row['OP4'];
                $array_respuestas=array($op1, $op2, $op3, $respuesta);

                for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
                  echo rand(0,count($array_respuestas));
                }

                  echo '<form action="Cactualiza.php?q=1&quiz='.$quiz.'&n='.$sn.'&idRes='.$id_Resultado.'&preg='.$pregunta.'&skip=no" method="POST" class="form-horizontal"><br />';
                  echo '<b>Pregunta &nbsp;'.$sn.'&nbsp;:<br />'.$pregunta.'</b><br /><br />';

                  if ($op1 !== "") {                  
                    if ($op1 === "PREGUNTA") {                      
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op1.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($op2 !== "") {
                    if ($op2 === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op2.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($op3 !== "") {
                    if ($op3 === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="0" required>'.$op3.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }if ($respuesta !== "") {
                    if ($respuesta === "PREGUNTA") {
                      echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="ans" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe tu respuesta aqui." required></textarea>';
                    }else{
                      echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="1" required>'.$respuesta.'<br /><br />';
                    }
                  }
                  echo'<br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Guardar</button></form></div>';
                }
```

Comment: No hacia falta poner otra respuesta, te hacía entendido y estaba escribiendo mi propia respuesta